# SafeModeOn-unable to boot-on a Dell OptiPlex GX286 with XP prof

Tags: windows-xp

My Dell OptiPlex GX286 with XP professional was working well. I disconnected all the cables to move the computer and now it does not start. It says is on `SAFE MODE`, however I cannot acces the computer as I don’t get any video input to the monitor apart from saying is on `SAFE MODE`.

I tried the <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd> and nothing seems to work. I didn’t try <kbd>ctrk</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>, which I should have done.

I took it to my local repair man, and it says I will need a new computer as much it is very old and is not supported. I do know that but it was working fine and it does the job I need it for. Any one there that can help, please.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, repair people are often lazy and this probably wasn't worth their time.

The likely cause here is that something came loose inside when you removed the cables and or moved it.  You will need to unplug and reseat everything until the problem goes away.
It is VERY likely that this will fix it.

Before doing ANY of these steps, REMOVE THE POWER CABLE is implied. ;)  Don't work on a machine that is plugged in.

Open the case:
https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-gx240_service%20manual_en-us.pdf

Remove the RAM, blow out the slot, replace the RAM.
Turn it on (case still open) try again.

Unplug HDD cables, replug HDD cables.
Turn it on (case still open) try again.

If you have ANY PCI cards, remove and re-install those too.
Turn it on (case still open) try again.

If it STILL doesn't work, try unplug the HDD and power on to see if something went bad with the drive preventing the BIOS from posting.

You have probably fixed your problem by now..
Close the case.

If not, you probably have a new boat anchor.
Good luck.